# Clico no botão salvar para cadastrar um produto no meu banco de dados e nada acontece HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin, visual-studio-code

Fiz um código em html + php para cadastrar produtos no meu banco de dados, a classe conexão esta funcionando pois o cadastro de clientes funciona e uso o mesmo include_once("conexão.php"). O form está como post e o action para meu arquivo de gravarproduto.php.

Quando eu clico no BtnSalvar nada acontece, não aparece erro, nem cadastra no banco. Segue a baixo os códigos:

Arquivo pgcadpro.php (cadastro de produtos)

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <div class="site-logo mr-auto w-25"><title>ImperialCalçados</title></div>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/icomoon/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("listacategorias.php",{}).done(function(dados){
          $("#sel_categoria").html(dados);
        }); 
            })             
    </script>
    <!-- cadcliente script -->
  </head>
  <div class="site-section bg-image overlay" style="background-image: url('images/vitrini.jpg');">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center testimony">
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="site-section" id="teachers-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mb-5 text-center"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
            <h2 class="section-title">Cadastrar Produto</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <form class="form-horizontal" >
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="gravaproduto.php">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtproduto">Produto : </label>  
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <input id="txtdescricao" name="txtdescricao" type="text" placeholder="Descrição do Produto" class="form-control input-md" required="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtgrupo">Categoria : </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <select name="sel_categoria" id="sel_categoria"  class="form-control">
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtcodigo_unidade_id">Valor : </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form name="teste">
      <input type="text" id="txtvalor" name="txtvalor" onkeyup="maskIt(this,event,'###.###.###,##',true,{pre:'R$'})"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btnsalvar"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="btnsalvar" name="btnsalvar" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    <button id="btncancelar" name="btncancelar" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
    <div class="site-section bg-image overlay" style="background-image: url('images/vitrini.jpg');">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center testimony">
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-section pb-0">
      <div class="future-blobs">
        <div class="blob_2">
          <img src="images/blob_2.svg" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="blob_1">
          <img src="images/blob_1.svg" alt="Image">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="border-top pt-5">
            <p>
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
        Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="icon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank" >Colorlib</a>
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
      </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
  </div> <!-- .site-wrap -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Arquivo grava produto:

```html
<?php
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=loja","root","aula");

    $descricao=$_POST["txtdescricao"];
    $idcategoria=$_POST["sel_categoria"];
    $valor=$_POST["txtvalor"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('Insert into loja.produto(descricao,valor,idcategoria)
    Values(:par_descricao,:par_valor,:par_idcategoria)');

    $dados=array(":par_descricao"=>$descricao,":par_valor"=>$valor,
    ":par_idcategoria"=>$idcategoria);
    
    $result = $stmt->execute($dados);
    
    if($result){
        echo ("Produto inserido com sucesso");
    }
    else{
        echo("Erro");
    } ?>

    <div class="form-group">
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="copyright">
            <div class="form-group caixa-pesquisa-div text-center">
            &copy; Copyright <strong>Imperial Calçados</strong>. Direitos Reservados <br /><br/>
                <input type="button" value="Voltar" onClick="history.go(-1)"style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #CC0000"> 
                <input type="button" value=" Sair  " onCLick="window.location.href = 'sair.php'" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #CC0000"> 
              </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você criou múltiplas tags `<form>` (uma dentro da outra) no seu código. Mantenha apenas uma, essa aqui:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="gravaproduto.php">
```

Ps: atente-se em fechar ela corretamente com apenas uma `</form>`

Esta tag `form` aqui é a problemática, altere-a por uma `div`:

```
<form name="teste">
  <input type="text" id="txtvalor" name="txtvalor" onkeyup="maskIt(this,event,'###.###.###,##',true,{pre:'R$'})"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado Alexandre, fiz a alteração porem ainda não salva no banco de dados, agora ele atualiza a pagina, e utilizando a ferramenta de desenvolvedor (F12) vi que deu erro na linha DOCTYPE> 
Erro: unchecked runtime lasterror the message port closed before a response was received

Comment: Agora deu certo, ainda estava com um form perdido aberto, Obrgado

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.

Comment: Alexandre, eu estou bloqueado de fazer perguntas porem só tenho uma percuntar com -2 pois esta como duplicada, não consigo excluir pois diz que pessoas ja investiram tempo com ela e ajudou algumas... o que fazer?